# creating and using lookup table based on AD value

Tags: c++, microcontroller

I am having a little bit of trouble creating and using a look up table.
My code is for a microcontroller that polls an 11 bit AD converter, and based on the value updates a 7 segment display.

The way i want to write the code is to create a table with 2047 values, each value has a binary pattern attached to it representing which pins and on and off, and then having the table return that binary value as int.

I am however not sure on the syntax to create the table or calling to it.

So far i got:

```
int table[2048][2];
j=0;
for(i=0; i<2048; i++)
{
    if(i%204==8)
    {
        j++;
    }

    if(j==0)
    {
        value=0x3F;
    }

    if(j==1)
    {
        value=0x06;
    }
    table[i][2]={i},{value}; 
}
```

the if statements keep going down to j==9, the value is the binary pattern I'm interested in returning.

Is this a smart way of approaching the problem?  if the AD value returned is for example 300, how would I look it up in the table to be able to get 0x06 as the number i want?

The bits for each of the second segments are

```
 111
6   2
6   2
 777
5   3
5   3
 444
```

So the digit 2 has bits 1, 2, 4, 5, and 7 set,and so is represented by 0x5B

Comment: Instead of making 2048 entries, why not use a table with 10 entries, 4 times?  Do you really have that much memory to waste?

Comment: are those bit patterns at least consistent/incrementing? Won't help much to have a loop if the bit patterns you need don't actually increment in the same way your loops do. e.g. i=3/j=4 = 1100110b, while i=3/j=5 is some completely different 0101001b, and i=3/j=6 something completely different again.

Comment: I'm also completely baffled as to the intent of the variable `j`, or what which bits of `value` correspond with which lights?

Comment: Bits 1,2 are one (which?) vertical edge, bit 7 is the line in the middle, but the rest?

Comment: @MooingDuck MSB in `value` is g, LSB is a, they go by alphabetical order.  `j` is used to keep track of when to change the value of `value`.  How would i go about using 10 entree table 4 times?

Comment: @user3862194: Which _light-segment_ is `a, b, c` etc?

Comment: @user3862194: this question is super underspecified, Why does each table entry have two values, the input and the bitpattern for the display for the input/8?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a *lot* of duplicated bits, with a lot of runtime overhead, and I can't even think of an efficient way to use it.  Why not a lookup table of each of the 10 decimal digits, and simply have a function assemble the result 1 decimal digit at a time?

```
static const unsigned char segment7digits = {
    0x3F, //0 -> 00111111 
    0x3F, //1 -> 00000110 
    0x5B, //2 -> 01011011
    0x4F, //3 -> 01001111
    0x66, //4 -> 01100110
    0x6D, //5 -> 01101101
    0x7D, //6 -> 01111101
    0x07, //7 -> 00000111
    0x7F, //8 -> 01111111
    0x6F, //9 -> 01101111
    }; //these values are untested and probably have errors

int lookup_7segment_bits(int value) {
   assert(value>=0 && value<=9999);
   int result;
   result  = segment7digits[value/1%10]; //least significant decimal digit
   result |= segment7digits[value/10%10]<<7;
   result |= segment7digits[value/100%10]<<14;
   result |= segment7digits[value/1000%10]<<21; //most significant decimal digit
   return result;
};
```

Comment: The LCD bits are correct, but it is the use of the table I'm struggling with.   could you explain this section? `result  = segment7digits[value/1%10]; //least significant decimal digit
   result |= segment7digits[value/10%10]<<7;
   result |= segment7digits[value/100%10]<<14;
   result |= segment7digits[value/1000%10]<<21;` what happens if i pass to it the number `300`?  wont the first line return 0x3F?

Comment: @user3862194: yes: `result  = segment7digits[value/1%10]` will assign the value `0x3F` to `result`.  The key part is the following lines: `result |= {STUFF} <<7;`, which assigns 0x3F (for the tens digit) to the _next_ seven bits, and then `result |= {STUFF} <<14;` assigns 0x4F (for the hundreds digit) to the _next_ seven bits, and the last line assigns 0x3F to the next seven bits for the thousands digit.  Those 28 bits represent `0300`. Is that not how multidigit numbers should be handled?  What would your code assign to the table for the value 300?

Comment: Or maybe each digit was supposed to be 8 bits?

Comment: I see where the confusion stems from now.  My code controls just a single display, so every 204 in the AD result register would increase the display digit by 1.  It's not suppose to display the entire analog value passed to it.  I was looking for a way to display that digit in a more efficient matter than just if-else statements.  Thank you, I have found it. Was drawing a blank on how arrays work.

Comment: @user3862194: Note also that my array stores `unsigned char`, so the whole array takes only 10 bytes as opposed to 16112 like your post does :D